# jQuery seems to have an enable function, but not a disable function. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Until now I was using the following to disable/enable form fields -

```
$('#fieldid').attr('disable','disable');
$('#fieldid').removeAttr('disable');
```

And that got the job done. But yesterday, I absent-mindedly typed the following to enable the field -

```
$('#fieldid').enable();
```

And it worked! I silently kicked myself for not trying the the handy 'enable'/'disable' functions built into jQuery (or so I thought), and proceeded to change the line to disable to -

```
$('#fieldid').disable();
```

And to my surprise, that did NOT work.

Am I missing something? Why is the enable() function defined but the disable() function is not? And even weirder, I could find no mention of either enable() or disable() in the jquery docs. Does anyone have any explanations?

I'm using jQuery 1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does not support an `enable()` method out of the box (and the `disable` HTML attribute does not exist either, but that might only be a typo in your question).

Maybe you're using a plug-in that provides that feature? If that's the case, try passing `false` to the `enable()` method to disable a field:

```
$('#fieldid').enable(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I actually meant to write disable**d**, instead of disable. And yes you are correct, $('#fieldid').enable(false); did disable the field. Turns out I had the jquery [form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin enabled!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear that. +1 for posting feedback with the name of the plugin providing the feature. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's available via the [disable plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/disable). As for *why* it's not included out of the box, I can only assume that it was left out as the functionality was already covered by `.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

I have read through the jquery code and the documentation but couldn't find any indicition of am enable function, are you sure the box isn't already enabled?

I created a jsfiddle to check:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zy3tW/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textinput").enable();
});

<input id="textinput" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```